# Sending a data list address in assembly

Tags: pointers, assembly, x86

This is a question from Programming from the Ground Up:

Convert the maximum program given in the Section called Finding a Maximum
Value in Chapter 3 so that it is a function which takes a pointer to several values
and returns their maximum. Write a program that calls maximum with 3
different lists, and returns the result of the last one as the program’s exit status
code.

Basically I'm trying to send the address of a list of numbers to a function, iterate through it until it hits a 0 and then returns the maximum value.

I can't figure out how to send (or at least operate) on an address to a function. It seems like I'm only receiving the value of the first element of the list, not the address.

Here's what I have so far:

```
.section .data
```

data_items:
          # list of numbers
          .long 3,67,34,236,2,222,45,75,54,34,44,33,22,11,66,1,0

.section .text

.globl _start
_start:
          pushl data_items
          call get_max
          addl $4, %esp
          movl %eax, %ebx
          movl $1, %eax
          int $0x80

.type get_max, @function
get_max:
          pushl %ebp
          movl %esp, %ebp
          movl 8(%ebp), %ecx # start of list in %ecx
          movl $0, %edx # index for %ecx
          movl (%ecx), %eax
          movl %eax, %ebx # %ebx = current maximum

get_max_loop:
          cmpl $0, %eax # stop when a 0 is found
          je get_max_end
          incl %edx
          addl $4, %ecx # trying to get next element in list
          movl (%ecx), %eax
          cmpl %ebx, %eax
          jle get_max_loop
          movl %eax, %ebx
          jmp get_max_loop

get_max_end:
          movl %ebp, %esp
          popl %ebp
          ret

Comment: So, what happens? Does it not compile? Does it crash, or give incorrect results? What error messages do you get, if any?

Comment: @Michael Just your average segfault. "run.sh: line 2: 10280 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./max_num
Exit code: 139"

Comment: Ok. I never use AT&T syntax myself, but shouldn't it be `pushl $data_items` if you wanted to push the address of `data_items`?

Comment: @Michael YES! That seems to work! Thank you. Now I'm just iterating through the list with "addl $4, %eax" where the address stored in %eax is the front of the list. I'm confused as to that syntax, though. (Doesn't seem like it was explained in this book yet.) Why is it that $0 would put a constant in a register, like with "movl $5, %eax" but $data_items would pass an address? That seems counter-intuitive. Is it the same operator with different functionality or am I wrong on how it works?

Comment: The address of `data_items` is an integer constant, so it's really no different from `$0` other than that it has been given a name (technically there are some differences, since `$0` would be known at assembly-time while the final address of `data_items` won't be known until at link-time, but that's not something you have to worry about at this point).